# How do I pull an instance of X509Certificate[] out of an SSLSocket?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Suppose I have the following code, which creates an SSL Socket to `google.com`, and I would like to view Google's certificate. How can I get an instance of `javax.security.cert.X509Certificate[]`?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.net.*;


public class MWE{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
        SocketFactory clientSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        String remoteHost = "google.com";
        int remotePort = 443;
        SSLSocket socket = null;
        try {
            //Lookup the "common name" field of the certificate from the remote server:
            socket = (SSLSocket) clientSocketFactory.createSocket(remoteHost, remotePort);
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            socket.startHandshake();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I have looked at the documentation for each of classes involved, but I have yet to find any references to any data structures containing the certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X509Certificate[] c = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificateChain();
```